# Hash that returns the same value for all numbers in range?

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, hashmap

I'm working on a problem where I have an entire table from a database in memory at all times, with a low range and high range of 9-digit numbers. I'm given a 9-digit number that I need to use to lookup the rest of the columns in the table based on whether that number falls in the range. For example, if the range was 100,000,000 to 125,000,000 and I was given a number 117,123,456, then I would know that I'm in the 100-125 mil range, and whatever vector of data that points to is what I will be using.

Now the best I can think of for lookup time is log(n) run time. This is OK, at best, but still pretty slow. The table has at least 100,000 entries and I will need to look up values in this table tens-of-thousands, if not hundred-thousands of times, per execution of this application (10+ times/day).

So I was wondering if it was possible to use an unordered_set instead, writing my own Hash function that ALWAYS returns the same hash-value for every number in range. Using the same example above, 100,000,000 through 125,000,000 will always return, for example, a hash value of AB12CD. Then when I use the lookup value of 117,123,456, I will get that same AB12CD hash and have a lookup time of O(1).

Is this possible, and if so, any ideas how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the range have equal intervals? and is the range continuous?
For eg: 0 - 1000, 1000 - 2000, 2000- 3000...

Comment: You want to write your own perfect hash function to avoid collisions? Have you tried using default `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: @stack_n_queue unfortunately not. In some cases the range is 1. In others, its millions.

Comment: @Snps I feel like you haven't grasped the idea I'm trying to get at. I'm USING an unordered_map, however I don't want the unordered map to have 1 billion entries in it. I want the map to return a different hash for every RANGE of entries.

Comment: Log2(100,000) is about 17, 17 comparisons is next to nothing.  Use sorted vectors, not maps.

Comment: Oh.  And a search in an unordered map has complexity N, not log2(N)

Comment: @MichaëlRoy yeah I'm using a standard map for the search. I didn't even think about the amount of comparisons being so minuscule. Perhaps I'll stick to this solution.

Comment: Sorry, I meant std::unordered_set.  std::map is a good choice.  But can't beat a sorted vector, it you want to extract a range, using std::upper_bound and lower_bound

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Assuming that you can number your intervals in order, you could fit a polynomial to your cutoff values, and receive an index value from the polynomial.  For instance, with cutoffs of 100,000,000, 125,000,000, 250,000,000, and 327,000,000, you could use points (100, 0), (125, 1), (250, 2), and (327, 3), restricting the first derivative to [0, 1].  Assuming that you have decently-behaved intervals, you'll be able to fit this with an (N+2)th-degree polynomial for N cutoffs.

Have a table of desired hash values; use floor[polynomial(i)] for the index into the table.

Comment: Wouldn’t evaluating this polynomial potentially be slower than just doing a binary search?

Comment: Potentially, yes ... but it's **O(1)**, which is the issue at hand.

Comment: Is the degree really O(1)? From the way the OP described things I thought that the table size could vary.

Comment: The size of the table can grow, and can potentially grow daily.

Comment: Splitting a table into several to look from is the same as no gain when you talk about Log(N) time.  Since that's basically what the binary search does when restricting the search range.

Comment: What is the complexity of your hash function?

Answer (score 0):

Can you write such a hash function?  Yes.  Will evaluating it be slower than a search?  Well there's the catch...

I would personally solve this problem as follows.  I'd have a sorted vector of all values.  And then I'd have a jump table of indexes into that vector based on the value of `n >> 8`.

So now your logic is that you look in the jump table to figure out where you are jumping to and how many values you should consider.  (Just look at where you land versus the next index to see the size of the range.)  If the whole range goes to the same vector, you're done.  If there are only a few entries, do a linear search to find where you belong.  If they are a lot of entries, do a binary search.  Experiment with your data to find when binary search beats a linear search.

A vague memory suggests that the tradeoff is around 100 or so because predicting a branch wrong is expensive.  But that is a vague memory from many years ago, so run the experiment for yourself.